# AS3 individual Event listener in for loop

Tags: actionscript-3, for-loop, event-listener

I couldn't find a better title to describe my problem.

I want to achieve this:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
     mc.addEventLister(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, function() {
        mc.y=-20;
     });
}
```

My problem is that mc always referrs to the last mc created in the for loop so the first mc created causes the last one to move on mouseover. Maybe I could use something like "this" or "self"...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do something like this:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
     mc.addEventLister(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, function(evt:Event) {
        evt.currentTarget.y=-20;
     });
}
```

Note, that instead of using `mc` I'm using the `currentTarget` of the event, which is what we added the event-listener to.

Comment: There is a potential problem with this solution in that with the current coding you will only be able to access the last mc created, e.g. if you wanted to remove the event listeners so movieclips were eligible for garbage collection. Another solution would be to add each mc to an array. i.e. mcArray.push(mc); You could then cycle through the array, accessing each instance of mc.

Comment: Yes, this solution is prone to memory leaks, but so is the original implementation and some other proposed implementations here. If you keep the MovieClips added to the stage until the application ends, there's no issue anyway. Or you could simply add the event-listener with `useWeakReference` set to true. Eg. `addEventLister(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, <function>, false, 0, true)`

Answer (score 3):

There are a bunch of ways to get around this, you could use the event object

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
     mc.addEventLister(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, function(e) {
        MovieClip(e.currentTarget).y=-20;
     });
}
```

Or you could use an anonymous closure to create a stable variable scope:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     (function(mc:MovieClip):void  {
        mc.addEventLister(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, function(e) {
            mc.y=-20;
        });
     })(new MovieClip());
}
```

Or a named function to do the same:

```
function attachListenerTo(mc:MovieClip):void {
    mc.addEventLister(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, function(e) {
        mc.y=-20;
    });
}

for(var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     attachListenerTo(new MovieClip());
}
```

Or you could make a subclass of MovieClip and attach the event listener in a bound context:

```
public dynamic class ChildClass extends MovieClip {
    public function ChildClass() {
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, handleOver);
    }

    private function handleOver(e:MouseEvent):void {
        this.y = -20;
    }
}

// And then

for(var i:uint=0;i<10;i++) {
    var mc:MovieClip = new ChildClass();
}
```

### Edit

Just a quick note as to *why* your first version fails, ActionScript does not have block scopes (unlike other languages like C#) and uses variable hoisting. This means the line `var mc:MovieClip` isn't where you think that it is. In fact, there is only one variable called `mc` and its bound to the functional scope, meaning that through each iteration of the loop you are just reassigning the single variable named `mc`. Since you are creating an anonymous function as your handler, it too gets bound to the same scope as `mc`. This is why `mc` always refers to the last MovieClip from the loop, by the time any of these closures get invoked, it is long after the loop has finished running and `mc` still points to the last one.

Comment: +1 for the 'anonymous closure to create a stable variable scope' answer! You have just saved me a lot of head scratching! Thanks for your response!