# MouseDown event not firing

Tags: actionscript-3

I have hundreds of movieclips constantly being created on a timer, each with a mouseDown event listener which will remove the movieclip on mouseDown. For nearly all the movieclips the mouseDown event seems to fire correctly, however sometimes I notice that the mouseDown event does not fire for a movieclip (i.e. it is not removed).

This is function creating the movieclip:

```
        public function pickShape():MovieClip {

        //possible shapes
        var shapes:Array = [new triangle(), new rectangle(), new square()]; 

        var randomCol:int = Math.floor(Math.random()*colours.length);

        var randomShape:int = Math.floor(Math.random()*shapes.length);

        var chosenShape:MovieClip = shapes[randomShape];

        //change shape to random colour
        var shapeCol:ColorTransform = chosenShape.transform.colorTransform;
        shapeCol.color = colours[randomCol];
        chosenShape.transform.colorTransform = shapeCol;


        chosenShape.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, destroyShape); //remove mc

        return chosenShape;
    }
```

pickShape() is called from another function which is called on a timerEvent, in this other function the scaleX, scaleY and rotation of chosenShape are altered. chosenShape will be moving across the screen in an EnterFrame, when it is offscreen it is removed.

What would cause this?

thanks for any help

Comment: may you post some code to help us to help you... have you tried to trace something to debug?

Comment: "however sometimes I notice that the mouseDown event does not fire for a movieclip (i.e. it is not removed)" That doesn't mean the mouse down is "not firing". You need to debug this further. Possibly the code that removes it is not working. Possibly you've removed the `mouseDown` handler. Possibly you've set `mouseEnabled=false`. Who knows!

Comment: I have tried tracing using if(!mc.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN) trace("no listener")) for all movieclips on the screen so I am pretty sure that the movieclip has the listener. I've edited my question to add some code

Comment: @Aaron I'm quite sure that mouseEnabled = true and mouseDown handler has not been removed.

Comment: What does the `destroyShape()` code look like? Is something covering up the object giving you trouble?

Comment: I have a custom cursor layered on top of the mouse? could this be causing the problem? In destroyShape()  the listener is removed and there is a tweenEvent which alters the alpha of the shape and removes it on MOTION_FINISH after 2 seconds.

Comment: "I have a custom cursor layered on top of the mouse?" Have you set the cursor to `mouseEnabled=false` and `mouseChildren=false`? If not, that could cause problems.

Comment: `mouseEnabled=false` yes, and `mouseChildren` was not set to false, I will set it to false and  see what happens. The problem with this "error" is that it occurs very infrequently, so is not really detectable unless I click numerous shapes...

Comment: you can try to trace chosenShape.name in pickShape, then trace event.currentTarget.name in destroyShape (then you know if there is a scope problem and if destroyShape is triggered).  Also the answer of @32bitkid on this post might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680717/as3-individual-event-listener-in-for-loop. You may also try your function without the tweenevent and its callback (by removing directly the target) and see what happens. If it works, it'a problem with the callback.

Comment: @Aaron @scraaappy thanks for your help. I think the issue has been solved by setting `mouseChildren=false`. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Does your destroyShape function looks like this:

```
function destroyShape(e:MouseEvent):void
{
e.currentTarget.parent.removeChild(e.currentTarget);
}
```

?